# What is the condition on the hypersurface, such that all height functions are Morse functions?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, morse-theory

When we choose the morse function of a hypersurface of affine space. We always choose a height function.

But when must a height function be a morse function？I mean, can we add some curvature conditions of the hypersurface, such that the projection to any one dimension linear subspace are morse functions automatically?

Comment: It can be shown using Sard's Theorem that the set of lines for which the associated height function is not a Morse function has measure zero

Comment: For instance, if your hypersurface is strictly convex, you will get this property. But this class will be quite restricted. It's unclear what kind of conditions you are interested in.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Excuse me，could you explain more explicitly why the convexity implys the result？Thanks！